# Using glossary in abbreviation causes issue: its written bold

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I'm currently working on a thesis and having trouble with my glossary in connection with abbreviations.

I define an abbreviation that way:

```
\acro{conMan}[CMS]{\gls{CMS}}
```

In my glossary list file i write:

```
\newglossaryentry{CMS}{
    name={Content Management System},
    description={My description comes here.}
}
```

By using:

```
\emph{\ac{conMan}}
```

it always prints "Content Management System" in bold+italic font. Its only with this one. I have several similar ones before that, an they are just written italic, as i defined.

How do I get it only italic too?

EDIT:

For further explanation: I want the following style, using the glossaries package for glossary entries and acronyms:

1) acronyms without a glossary entry in background shall be written italic in the text

Example: TH => Technical Highschool => Technical Highschool is not explained inside a glossary

2) acronyms with a glossary entry in background shall also be written italic in the text, but in the index they shall be written bold and reference to the glossary

Example: CMS => Content Management System <-- is written italic in text, but bold in index of acronyms => Content Management System is explained in glossary

3) glossary entries are written bold in the text

Example: I use the Word "Web-App" in the text, so i want it to be written bold, because its in my glossary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You haven't provided a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) but it looks like you're using both `acronym` and `glossaries`, but since `glossaries` also does acronyms you only need to load one package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{CMS}{
    name={Content Management System},
    description={My description comes here.}
}

\newacronym{conMan}{CMS}{\gls{CMS}}

\begin{document}

First use: \emph{\ac{conMan}}. Next use: \emph{\ac{conMan}}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]

**Edit:** To make glossary entries bold and acronyms not bold:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries}

\renewcommand*{\CustomAcronymFields}{%  
  name={\the\glslongtok},%  
  symbol={\the\glsshorttok},%  
  text={\textmd{\the\glsshorttok}},%  
  first={\the\glslongtok\space\textmd{(\the\glsshorttok)}},%  
  firstplural={\the\glslongtok\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix\space\textmd{(\the\glsshorttok)}},%  
  plural={\textmd{\the\glsshorttok}\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix}%  
} 

\SetCustomStyle 

\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\textbf{#1}} 

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{CMS}{
    name={Content Management System},
    description={My description comes here.}
}

\newacronym{conMan}{CMS}{\gls{CMS}}

\begin{document}

First use: \emph{\ac{conMan}}. Next use: \emph{\ac{conMan}}.

Reset\glsreset{conMan}. Now without the emphasis:

First use: \ac{conMan}. Next use: \ac{conMan}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

If you don't want the acronym affected by the surrounding font (such as `\emph` in the above example), replace `\textmd` with `\textnormal` in the `\CustomAcronymFields` definition.

Result:

[image: Image of result]

**Edit:**

In this example below, I've defined a new command called `\newglosacr` for the acronyms that also have entries in the glossary. The acronyms are emphasized and the glossary terms are in bold:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries}

\renewcommand*{\acronymfont}[1]{\emph{\mdseries #1}}

\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\textbf{#1}} 

\renewcommand*{\CustomAcronymFields}{%  
  name={\noexpand\acronymfont{\the\glsshorttok}},%  
  sort={\the\glsshorttok},%  
  symbol={\the\glsshorttok},%  
  text={\noexpand\acronymfont{\the\glsshorttok}},%  
  first={\textmd{\the\glslongtok}\space
           \noexpand\acronymfont{(\the\glsshorttok)}},%  
  firstplural={\textmd{\the\glslongtok\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix}\space
    \noexpand\acronymfont{(\the\glsshorttok)}},%  
  plural={\noexpand\acronymfont{\the\glsshorttok}\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix},%  
  description={\the\glslongtok}
} 

\SetCustomStyle 

\makeglossaries

% Glossary entries

\newglossaryentry{CMS}{
    name={Content Management System},
    description={My description comes here}
}

\newglossaryentry{webapp}{name={Web-App},
  description={Description here}
}

% Acronyms without links to glossary

\newacronym{th}{TH}{Technical Highschool}

% Acronyms with links to glossary

% syntax: \newglosacr[options]{new acr label}{acronym}{referenced gls label}
\newcommand{\newglosacr}[4][]{%
  \newacronym[description={\gls{#4} (see
     glossary)},#1]{#2}{#3}{\glsentryname{#4}}%
}

\newglosacr{conMan}{CMS}{CMS}

\begin{document}

First use: \ac{conMan}. Next use: \ac{conMan}.

First use: \ac{th}. Next use: \ac{th}.

Term without acronym: \gls{webapp}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

I've added the `hyperref` package to the example so you can hyperlink to the glossary. I don't know if you want that or not. Since the glossary entry `CMS` is only used in the list of acronyms, not in the main text, you need to repeat the `LaTeX` + `makeglossaries` steps. I've added some [`arara`](http://cereda.github.io/arara/) directives at the top of the example code as a reminder, but you can ignore them if you don't want to use it.

Result:

[image: Image of resulting document]

Comment: I added a further description to my question. i hope this helps!